# I want to delete the selected element in an array in java

Tags: java

I want to delete the selected element in an array in java, for example deleting `3,5,8` in

```
int[]={3,2,5,6,4,8,9}
```

Comment: an array is a fixed length, you want either to use an arraylist (which is not fixed length) or create a new int[]

Comment: go ahead buddy you can delete it

Comment: `int[index] = 0;` remove you replace with 0 or use `ArrayList`.

Comment: I've down-voted you because you've presented no evidence of prior research or effort on your part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Arrays have a fixed length, and the only way to "delete" them would be to either use for example zero to mark a "deleted" entry, or to create a new smaller array and copy all but the "deleted" entries there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it :

```
array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, element)
```

[Documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#removeElement%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayUtils class to remove an element

```
 array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array,element)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays cannot be resized**, so you either create a new array and copy the desired elements from the old one (use `System.arraycopy(..)`) for that, or better: use a `Collection` such as `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.